# Make element visible when Validation.HasError is true

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, visibility

I have the following xaml markup:

```xml
            <GroupBox Margin="10" Padding="20" Header="Case 5 - Custom Error Object">
                <GroupBox.DataContext>
                    <local:ViewModel4/>
                </GroupBox.DataContext>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Name="AdornerElement" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AdornerElementStyle}"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
                             Margin="0 10"
                             Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding ElementName=AdornerElement}">
                    </TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
```

and the following style:

```xml
        <Style x:Key="AdornerElementStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightCoral">
                            <Image Source="/clipart.png" Width="24" Margin="10"/>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=AdornerElement, Path=(Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.Errors)}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ErrorContent.ValidationMessage}"
                                                   Style="{StaticResource CustomErrorTypeStyle}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AdornerElement, Path=Validation.HasError}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Everything works fine except Trigger.

If I set up the property "Visibility" to "Visible" initially, then I can see that error messages are shown correctly.

[image: The result I want to get]

If I use style shown before, then the Label remains to be collapsed.

Please, help me to use triggers correctly to achieve the final result.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `Validation.ValidationAdornerSite` works. This attached property just defines the element that will be adorned with the validation error template. By default this is the element that is validating, the `Binding.Target` to be more precise.
When you set `Validation.ValidationAdornerSite` the binding engine will automatically set the attached `Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor` property to reference the element that `Validation.ValidationAdornerSite` was originally set on.

This means that `Validation.HasError` and other related attached properties are always set on the `Binding.Target` and not on the adorner site.
That's why your triggers don't work: they are triggering on the `Label` instead of the `TextBox` (where the validation/binding error is registered).

To fix it, the `DataTrigger` must get the `Validation.HasErrors` attached property value of the `Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor` attached property, which references the original `Binding.Target` (the `TextBox`).

```xml
<Style x:Key="AdornerElementStyle"
       TargetType="Label">
  <Setter Property="Visibility"
          Value="Collapsed" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Background="LightCoral">
          <Image Source="/clipart.png"
                 Width="24"
                 Margin="10" />
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=AdornerElement, Path=(Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.Errors)}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.ValidationMessage}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AdornerElement, Path=(Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.HasError)}"
                       Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Visible" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

### Remarks

It's not clear why you are using a `Label` to display the error messages. You could simply define an error template, which is a `ControlTemplate` that is referenced by the attached `Validation.ErrorTemplate` property. This would simplify your code significantly.

The following example creates the exact same visual error feedback but without the hassle for an additional `Label` and associated triggers to manage the visibility of the error messages. All this is all handled by the WPF binding engine.

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- The Validation.Errors property is the DataContext of this template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
      <StackPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="LightCoral">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/clipart.png"
                    Width="24"
                    Margin="10" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center">
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.ValidationMessage}" />
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">

          <!-- Placeholder for the Binding.Target -->
          <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="AdornedElement" />
        </Border>
      </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Resource>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResoucre ErrorTemplate}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is this a question? I'm sorry but I don't understand you. Maybe you can rephrase your comment?

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. But, there is one more issue that I can't explain myself. If we have the following string of binding property `<DataTrigger Binding="Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.HasError)}"`, it doesn't work. It requires to set element name explicitly, despite at ItemsControl works fine.

Comment: Regarding your Remark. Example in the question is not a final target what I want to do. It just an example. The target is to have one element to show errors from several edit elements. That's why, as I understand, your example will not work.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked button "Add comment" too earlier. Then I edited my comment too long and I had to delete my first comment eventually, wrote another.

Comment: The triggers are not part of the visual tree. Therefore RelativeSource doesn't resolve. If you want to trigger outside the ControlTemplate e.g. on properties of the templated parent, you can and should always use `Style.Triggers`. Just move the current DataTrigger from `ControlTemplate.Triggers` to `Style.Triggers` and change the `DataTrigger.Binding` to use `RelativeSpource.Self`. The trigger would look as follows:: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.HasError)}"`